# angular js filter with array of id's

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4

> span class="list-group-item" ng-click="filterByCtg = {ctgid:'12'}">category
>
> div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:search | filter:filterByCtg  |orderBy:orderByFilter:reverse">

I want to give filterByCtg an array of id's that are sub categories and sub sub categories.
how can i achieve this?

the filter doesnt work when im giving it an array.

sorry for bad engish.

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: sorry, its on a framework and i dont think i can or know how to jsfiddle with all the php...sorry for being a noob, ill try to explain better: i have a list<ul> with <li> and so on, that is my "menu" for a product catalog, the li's are passing a category id to the filter and the filter works. but i want to pass the filter multiple id's, so it will show subcategories.

Comment: according to the docs the filter expression can be a string, object, or a function. It doesn't say anything about passing a an array. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: can i somehow achieve this with custom filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom filter is exactly the right answer. A stub for it would look something like this:

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function(input, query) {
      var result = [];

      // Now do whatever you want to create the 'result' array
      // input will contain the source to the ng-repeat, categories
      // query will contain whatever you gave it as a parameter - see below
      // You should return an array of items. Each item will become 'entry' in the ng-repeat

      return result;
   };
 });
```

and you would use it like this:

```
<div class="whatever" ng-repeat="entry in categories | myFilter:someParameter track by $index"></div>
```

Note that you can set `$scope.someParameter = 'A';` and that will be passed into your filter as `query`.

Also, note that your filter is just like any other Angular module now. It can do a lot of clever things, like asking for a service to be injected that it can get things like subcategory data from. But be aware that this is a ***performance sensitive*** section of code. Your filter will get run a lot more than you expect because many things will trigger Angular to verify that this list has not changed. Therefore you should make this as efficient as possible.